# high sample rate data for ARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima

I have some time-series data that has a very high sample rate.  Viz.  The sensors take a measurement every second or so, but patterns don't really emerge until the timescale of hours ~3600 timesteps.  The problem is that if I build an ARIMA model on the per-second data, and then try to predict an hour in advance, that is a 3600 timestep prediction, which will not work well.  On the other hand, I could subsample my data to be one reading per hour, build a model, and then get decent predictions for a couple of hours out.  However, it doesn't seem like the best thing to do would be to just *throw away* a bunch of data.  What is the best practice for building time-series models with high-sample-rate data?  Where can I read more about dealing with this problem?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to exhaust all the downsampling methods. Does this Wikipedia page help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)

Comment: I don't necessarily want to exhaust them, I just want to know what methods an expert time-series analyst would consider in such a situation, specifically in the context of building a predictive model, so that I when I talk to people about the model I built it sounds like I know what I'm doing.  =c)